# Ошибка при попытке загрузить файл на сервер php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, redbeanphp

Когда загружаю файл, он появляется в папке, але одновременно выводит ошибка Fatal error: Uncaught [HY000] - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'image' doesn't have a default value trace ...

```
<?php
require "db.php";

$data = $_POST;

if ( isset($data['add_news']) ) {

    $errors = array();

    if (trim($data['title']) == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Введите Название статьи!';
    }

    if (trim($data['content']) < 100) {
        $errors[] = 'Статья должна быть развернута!';
    }

    if ( empty($errors) and $_FILES ) {
        $post = R::dispense('posts');

        $post->title = $data['title'];
        $post->content = $data['content'];

        R::store($post);

        $image = $uploaddir."img".$post["id"].".jpg";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'file/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);

        header ('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo '<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 100px; color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
    }
}
```

?>

Форма

```
<form class="write" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row__form">
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Название статьи" required>
            <select name="categoria" class="dropdown-select">
              <option value="1">Игры</option>
              <option value="2">Книги</option>
              <option value="3">Фильмы и сериалы</option>
              <option value="4">Wires</option>
              <option value="5">Техника</option>
              <option value="6">Программирование</option>
            </select>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="image" class="image" required>
        </div>
        <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="20" placeholder="Напишите статью которая заинтересует посетителя"></textarea>

        <button type="submit" class="button" name="add_news">Добавить</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Загуглить у вас бы заняло меньше времени нежели написать целый вопрос.

Comment: Раз уж вы знаете ответ так скажите. Просто я хз что делать

Comment: Задал вопрос меньше 5 минут заняло времени, а гуглил более 2-х часов

Comment: @Taras, разбираться ...

Comment: Я думал что здесь людям помагают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас в базе есть колонка **image** и она не может быть пустой допишите в коде

```php
 $post->image  = "img".$post["id"].".jpg";
```

Comment: Господи, спасибо вам :)